# Add condition to this INDEX MATCH formula if it returns #N/A

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a formula in Sheet3 to look up a value from sheet1 and return it, but sometimes, if values are not in sheet1, I want it to check in sheet2. sheet1 and sheet2 have same data in column A:A, only columns have different values.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,MATCH(Sheet3!A2&"MAN_CHANGE",Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

How can I modify the formula to check in sheet2 if there's not a match in sheet1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glad to hear from you again!) Try this please:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,IFERROR(MATCH(Sheet3!A2&"MAN_CHANGE",Sheet1!A:A,0),MATCH(Sheet3!A2&"MAN_CHANGE",Sheet2!A:A,0)))
```

Comment: I eneded up changing formula to `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&"MAN_CHANGE",Sheet1!A:D,4,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A2&"MAN_CHANGE",Sheet2!A:D,4,FALSE))` Since for previous formula `Index(Sheet1!D:D,` was still looking to grab value from there.

Comment: @Mowgli I think that's the best case possible - when you're not just copy&paste the answer provided, but may easily adopt it fir your further needs with complete understanding WHAT & WHY)

Answer (score 2):

iferror will check for any error result from the index formula

```
=iferror(INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,MATCH(Sheet3!A2&"MAN_CHANGE",Sheet1!A:A,0)),"NOT FOUND")
```

Alternatively you could use isNA to search just for #N/A

```
=if(ISNA(INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,MATCH(Sheet3!A2&"MAN_CHANGE",Sheet1!A:A,0)),"NOT FOUND",INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,MATCH(Sheet3!A2&"MAN_CHANGE",Sheet1!A:A,0)))
```

Answer (score -1):

I nested two INDEX,MATCH formulas and it worked.

=IFERROR(INDEX('Activity Report 11-30-17'!G:G,MATCH('Recon Report 11-30-17'!C2,'Activity Report 11-30-17'!D:D,0)),INDEX('Activity Report 11-30-17'!G:G,MATCH('Recon Report 11-30-17'!D2,'Activity Report 11-30-17'!D:D,0)))

Comment: That is just terrible, unreadable and impossible to maintain.